# Access 2003 display percentage of total records in report form

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called TestTable with 3 fields called A,B and C

I'm trying to display on an Access 2003 report form the total number of records returned via a query in one textbox - Control Source set to `"=Count(*)",` and that works ok, and in another textbox display this value as a percentage of the total numbers of records, something like,

```
(Count(*)/total) * 100
```

But I'm having problems displaying the correct value in the second (percentage) textbox. I've tried setting a global variable to this value through the use of `DCount("*", "TestTable")` as part of an OpenRecordset Sub.  This method works in the main user form however I can't seem to use such variables in a control source for this record.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DCount("*", "TestTable")` directly!
Why set a global variable?!

In the percentage textbox `ControlSource` property should be:

```
=(Count(*)/DCount("*", "TestTable")) * 100
```

BTW: If you set the `Format` property to `Percent` you can miss out the `* 100`

FYI: In order to access global variables from a `ControlSource` property you must use a function that returns the value of the global. Globals themselves are not accessible.

Comment: Many thanks for a great, simple solution!...thanks also for the tip about using the function method in the ControlSource (more resources but handy for some other uses)....I've learnt a bit more.